# Iptables port forward tftpd

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking

i need to forward incoming port 69 to port 2112 with iptables on linux.
i don't need any NAT etc. just accept incoming connections to port 2112 like it be 69 pot.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 69 -j REDIRECT --to-port 2112
```

Comment: And when i run your command nothing still applied to iptables.

Comment: @Raspizdyay: Did you list the correct table ? `iptables -t nat -L`  ?

Comment: but why nat? there is no nat on my computer it is just an imput

Comment: @Raspizdyay: Port forwarding is address translation and takes place in the PREROUTING chain of the NAT table.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the port forwarding, you also need an extra module loaded to handle tracking tftp connections. This can be done in testing by simply running

> modprobe nf_conntrack_tftp

Making it permanent depends on the distro in use, but you generally just need to put it in /etc/modules so it will be loaded at boot.